# "Better way" questions on Stack Overflow

Tags: discussion, scope, asking-questions

When you type "Better way" in Stack Overflow search box, you will find a lot of questions where people try to find better solutions (simplest, fastest, more portable) that they know/use currently.

Last time I asked "Better way" question (I use sentence: *"Is there simpler way (than above code/solution)"* ), but the question was deleted. One person commented to say that:

> Asking "what can I do better/simpler/" or whatever just isn't allowed.

But that person did not provide a link to this rule.

So I wonder: Are "Better way" questions off-topic or not in formal point of view? (If yes provide link to the appropriate rules)

Comment: See also: [A guide to Code Review for Stack Overflow users](https://codereview.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5777/a-guide-to-code-review-for-stack-overflow-users) ([codereview.meta.stackexchange.com](https://codereview.meta.stackexchange.com))

Comment: If you have code that "works", but it doesn't meet a required goal (such as a specific performance goal) then the problem you're asking for a solution to is not solved by the the code you've provided, and you can definitely ask how to achieve that goal; so long as you properly describe the problem you're trying to solve and make sure the question is reasonably scoped and well-defined (unambiguous, not open to interpretation).

Comment: At best you can have a prejudice against the bucket filled with "better way questions", they are likely to be low quality or even off-topic. But there are no guarantees, so you're still tasked to judge each question on its own merit.

Comment: Basically never use the word "better", as it is subjective and could mean anything. Use "faster", "more readable", "more portable" and similar. The reader of the question shouldn't have to guess the meaning.

Comment: @KamilKiełczewski That's still subjective. Simpler in terms of readability, or simpler for the programmer to write, or in terms of program complexity or execution speed, or memory consumption?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Without a **very clear and objective definition** on how "better" is to be understood for the purposes of your question, such questions are *primarily opinion based* and/or *too broad*; and thus liable of being downvoted, closed, and ultimately deleted.

If you take the effort into making a question like this on-topic, you'll need to **focus on a specific and practical** angle of "improvement" for your code; and as a result the question will very likely stop being a *"better/simpler way"* question statement.

There is no specific rule against *"better way"* questions, in the same way that there is no specific rule against *"tuna cooking recipes"* questions. The rules cover topicality and scope, and they already cover the kind of question you are describing.

Read the [on-topic](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and [don't ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask) pages in the help center, for example

Comment: Some examples of "very clear and objective definition" wouldn't go amiss: time complexity, memory complexity, performance (measured with some reliability). Ideally, you can *show* the level of your current algorithm and *indicate* what you want to achieve and why you think it *should* be possible.

Comment: @jpp Even those types of criteria often aren't adequately specific.  Dumping some code and saying, "How can this use less memory" is still both very broad and, oftentimes, subjective.  The same problems often apply to performance.

Comment: @Servy, That's why I qualified it by the `Ideally,....` part.

Comment: @jpp You're saying it'd be nice, I'm saying it's *necessary*, and that the question is probably close worthy without it.